# Setting band 4 of raster to alpha with GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal

I have a raster which has 4 bands, however band 4 is not being interpreted as an alpha channel. When I run gdalinfo I get the follow information about the bands:

```
Band 1 Block=360000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
Band 2 Block=360000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 3 Block=360000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
Band 4 Block=360000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Band 1 Block=360000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=360000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=360000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
 Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=360000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

I am able to do this in QGIS by setting the band 4 to transparent and then rendering out the raster.

Is there a way of changing the "ColorInterp" in GDAL as I want to automate the process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be doable with gdal_edit.py http://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html

> **-colorinterp_X** red|green|blue|alpha|undefined:
>
> (GDAL >= 2.3) Change the color interpretation of band X (where X is a valid band number, starting at 1)

The whole command would look like

```
gdal_edit -colorinterp_1 red -colorinterp_2 green -colorinterp_3 blue -colorinterp_4 alpha image.tif
```

Comment: Great, I found that GDAL's translate tool in QGIS also supports this command:   
colorinterp_X <red|green|blue|alpha|gray|undefined>